Circled numbers ❶, ❷, etc. as bullets and in paragraphs
I'm trying to use circled numbers (❶, ❷, etc.) as bullets and generally in text.
I'm using XeLaTeX from Pandoc, but I'm not afraid of some inline TeX expressions or editing the template that Pandoc uses.
Usually Unicode characters just work with XeTeX, but these ones are not defined for the font I'm using (Palatino). On my system (macOS) when a character is not defined, a fallback is used from the "Apple Symbols" font. Not sure how to achieve a similar effect in my document, or some other way around.
Even worse, I want these to use as bullet points in an ordered list—is there a way to achieve that?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,lipsum}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\usepackage[small,sf,bf]{titlesec}

\setromanfont{Palatino}
\setsansfont{Tahoma}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

% Rendered as: ⎕, ⎕ :-(
Circled numbers: ❶, ❷

% Make same but with circled numbers
% instead of 1., 2.?
\begin{enumerate}
  \item One
  \item Two
\end{enumerate}

More text

\end{document}

Update
Sorry, something that was not clear:

I need the exact Unicode glyphs from the fonts I pick (need to match figures produced elsewhere).
I want to use the glyphs in source too.
I want to continue using Markdown lists, see below:

Pandoc Markdown allows to embed html and latex into the document. So for circled numbers I was able to do this:
<div class="circled-numbers">

1. One
2. Two

</div>

I really wish to achieve similar with LaTeX, because I target both HTML and PDF. Something like this, perhaps:
\startcirclednumbers
<div class="circled-numbers">

1. One
2. Two

</div>
\endcirclednumbers

Pandoc will convert the above into:
\startcirclednumbers
\begin{enumerate}
  \item One
  \item Two
\end{enumerate}
\endcirclednumbers


Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

There is no need to be afraid of tex expressions. If you embrace them, you could use the circledsteps package to produce circled numbers.

circledsteps looks interesting, but I really need the actual unicode glyphs: ❶, ❷, etc.

Did you try to change to another font (than Palatino) just for rendering Unicode symbols.

Unless your audience is limited to Mac users, the HTML and PDF will obviously look different to a significant chunk of your audience because Apple Symbols will be embedded in the PDF (or a subset will), but the HTML will have to substitute something available elsewhere or, more likely than not, show readers missing character symbols. If having it match what's displayed elsewhere is important, the first thing to ensure is that at least symbols with the correct meanings are available everywhere (or as close to everywhere as you can manage). HTML is never going to look the same to me as you.

PDF will have fonts embedded, and is only used for printing. Changing fonts so late in the project is impossible (figures have been drawn…). I don't worry too much about HTML—there the requirements are much more lax than for a print book.

So use the DejaVu solution below but define Apple Symbols as an additional font face rather than your main font? If you use enumitem you can probably even get the enumeration to work with some patience. Look at it and/or Babel .ldf files to see how they handle ordinals.

Option 1: Use a font with the glyphs as DejaVu Sans.
Option 2: Use the pifont package.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans} 
\usepackage{pifont}
\begin{document}
❶ ❷ ❸ ❹ ❺ ❻ ❼ ❽ ❾ ❿
\begin{enumerate}
\item[\ding{182}] Foo  
\item[\ding{191}] Foo 
\item[\ding{192}] Foo 
\item[\ding{201}] Foo 
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}

But both options are limited to a small set of numbers and with specific fonts and you must set the numbers of the items manually or it is not trivial to obtain an automatic enumeration.
Option 3: Make the circles with latex code, for example with Tikz. This option is not limited to small numbers, will match with any font, allows an easy automatic numeration of the items, and at least with Tikz is very customizable.

\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%
            \node[shape=circle, color=gray, fill=black,  text=white,
            draw,inner sep=1pt] (char) {\bfseries #1};}}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\protect\circled{\arabic*}]
\item \lipsum[1][1-2]
\item \lipsum[2][1-2]
\item \lipsum[3][1-2] \setcounter{enumi}{227}
\item foo\lipsum[4][1-1]
\end{enumerate}
\newpage
\renewcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%
            \node[shape=rectangle,
            rounded corners=6pt, 
             top color=yellow!10!,
             bottom color=cyan!70!magenta, 
             blur shadow={shadow blur steps=3}, 
            %%% fill=red!20, 
            color=black!30!blue,
            draw, inner sep=3pt] (char) {\color{blue}\bfseries\sffamily #1};}}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\protect\circled{\arabic*}]
\item \lipsum[1][1-2]
\item \lipsum[2][1-2]\setcounter{enumi}{27}
\item \lipsum[3][1-2] \setcounter{enumi}{753}
\item \lipsum[4][1-2]\setcounter{enumi}{9985}
\item \lipsum[5][1-2]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}


You can set up the negative circled numbers to use a font of your choice which contains them. I used Noto Serif CJK SC because it was the first serif font I found on my system that supported all the way up to twenty.
Then use the enumitem package to customise labels to use these circled numbers.
MWE
% Tex Program = xelatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{parskip}

% font set up
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\setromanfont{Noto Serif}
\newfontface{\circlednum}{Noto Serif CJK SC}

% define circled numbers
\newunicodechar{❶}{{\circlednum ❶}}
\newunicodechar{❷}{{\circlednum ❷}}
\newunicodechar{❸}{{\circlednum ❸}}
\newunicodechar{❹}{{\circlednum ❹}}
\newunicodechar{❺}{{\circlednum ❺}}
\newunicodechar{❻}{{\circlednum ❻}}
\newunicodechar{❼}{{\circlednum ❼}}
\newunicodechar{❽}{{\circlednum ❽}}
\newunicodechar{❾}{{\circlednum ❾}}
\newunicodechar{❿}{{\circlednum ❿}}
\newunicodechar{⓫}{{\circlednum ⓫}}
\newunicodechar{⓬}{{\circlednum ⓬}}
\newunicodechar{⓭}{{\circlednum ⓭}}
\newunicodechar{⓮}{{\circlednum ⓮}}
\newunicodechar{⓯}{{\circlednum ⓯}}
\newunicodechar{⓰}{{\circlednum ⓰}}
\newunicodechar{⓱}{{\circlednum ⓱}}
\newunicodechar{⓲}{{\circlednum ⓲}}
\newunicodechar{⓳}{{\circlednum ⓳}}
\newunicodechar{⓴}{{\circlednum ⓴}}

% define \circled macro to convert counter to circled number (based on \alph
% from latex.ltx)
\makeatletter
\def\circled#1{\expandafter\@circled\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\def\@circled#1{%
  \ifcase#1\or ❶\or ❷\or ❸\or ❹\or ❺\or ❻\or ❼\or ❽\or ❾\or ❿\or
   ⓫\or ⓬\or ⓭\or ⓮\or ⓯\or ⓰\or ⓱\or ⓲\or ⓳\or ⓴\else\@ctrerr\fi}

% use \circled macro in enumerate
\usepackage{enumitem}
\AddEnumerateCounter\circled\@circled{⓴}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\circled*}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
We can enter numbers directly as Unicode characters:

❶ ❷ ❸ ❹ ❺ ❻ ❼ ❽ ❾ ❿ ⓫ ⓬ ⓭ ⓮ ⓯ ⓰ ⓱ ⓲ ⓳ ⓴

We can also use the \texttt{enumerate} environment. Numbers beyond 20 generate
and error.

\begin{enumerate}
  \item one
  \item two
  \item three
  \item four
  \item five
  \item size
  \item seven
  \item eight
  \item nine
  \item ten
  \item eleven
  \item twelve
  \item thirteen
  \item fourteen
  \item fifteen
  \item sixteen
  \item seventeen
  \item eighteen
  \item nineteen
  \item twenty
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}


Markdown
Couple of things to note for using Pandoc to go from Markdown to PDF:

You have to disable the latex_macros extension to stop Pandoc from expanding macros. It does this in a non-clever way and produces broken LaTeX code.
Pandoc inserts \def\labelenumi{\arabic{enumi}.} at the beginning of enumerate environments. So I used a couple of hooks to redefine it back again to use \circled at the first \item. With this hook, we can dispense with the enumitem package.

The example below works for me now if I compile with:
pandoc --pdf-engine=xelatex -f markdown-latex_macros -i test.md -o test.pdf

Markdown MWE
---
title: Markdown with negative circled numbers
author: Vladimir Keleshev
mainfont: NotoSerif-Regular.ttf
header-includes: |
    \usepackage{newunicodechar}
    \newfontface{\circlednum}{Noto Serif CJK SC}
    \newunicodechar{❶}{{\circlednum ❶}}
    \newunicodechar{❷}{{\circlednum ❷}}
    \newunicodechar{❸}{{\circlednum ❸}}
    \newunicodechar{❹}{{\circlednum ❹}}
    \newunicodechar{❺}{{\circlednum ❺}}
    \newunicodechar{❻}{{\circlednum ❻}}
    \newunicodechar{❼}{{\circlednum ❼}}
    \newunicodechar{❽}{{\circlednum ❽}}
    \newunicodechar{❾}{{\circlednum ❾}}
    \newunicodechar{❿}{{\circlednum ❿}}
    \newunicodechar{⓫}{{\circlednum ⓫}}
    \newunicodechar{⓬}{{\circlednum ⓬}}
    \newunicodechar{⓭}{{\circlednum ⓭}}
    \newunicodechar{⓮}{{\circlednum ⓮}}
    \newunicodechar{⓯}{{\circlednum ⓯}}
    \newunicodechar{⓰}{{\circlednum ⓰}}
    \newunicodechar{⓱}{{\circlednum ⓱}}
    \newunicodechar{⓲}{{\circlednum ⓲}}
    \newunicodechar{⓳}{{\circlednum ⓳}}
    \newunicodechar{⓴}{{\circlednum ⓴}}
    \makeatletter
    \def\circled#1{\expandafter\@circled\csname c@#1\endcsname}
    \def\@circled#1{%
      \ifcase#1\or ❶\or ❷\or ❸\or ❹\or ❺\or ❻\or ❼\or ❽\or ❾\or ❿\or
       ⓫\or ⓬\or ⓭\or ⓮\or ⓯\or ⓰\or ⓱\or ⓲\or ⓳\or ⓴\else\@ctrerr\fi}
    \makeatother
    \AddToHook{env/enumerate/begin}{%
      \AddToHookNext{cmd/item/before}{%
        \def\labelenumi{\circled{enumi}}}}
---

# Section heading

We can enter numbers directly as Unicode characters:

❶ ❷ ❸ ❹ ❺ ❻ ❼ ❽ ❾ ❿ ⓫ ⓬ ⓭ ⓮ ⓯ ⓰ ⓱ ⓲ ⓳ ⓴

We can also use the `enumerate` environment. Numbers beyond 20 generate
and error.

1. one
2. two
3. three
4. four
5. five
6. size
7. seven
8. eight
9. nine
10. ten
11. eleven
12. twelve
13. thirteen
14. fourteen
15. fifteen
16. sixteen
17. seventeen
18. eighteen
19. nineteen
20. twenty


If you just needed these lists sometimes, then you could define your \startcirclednumbers to call the hook to set the set style at the next \item command. \endcirclednumbers is not necessary but could be defined as \relax for semantic completeness.
Again compile with:
pandoc --pdf-engine=xelatex -f markdown-latex_macros -i test.md -o test.pdf

MWE
---
mainfont: NotoSerif-Regular.ttf
header-includes: |
    \usepackage{newunicodechar}
    \newfontface{\circlednum}{Noto Serif CJK SC}
    \newunicodechar{❶}{{\circlednum ❶}}
    \newunicodechar{❷}{{\circlednum ❷}}
    \newunicodechar{❸}{{\circlednum ❸}}
    \newunicodechar{❹}{{\circlednum ❹}}
    \newunicodechar{❺}{{\circlednum ❺}}
    \newunicodechar{❻}{{\circlednum ❻}}
    \newunicodechar{❼}{{\circlednum ❼}}
    \newunicodechar{❽}{{\circlednum ❽}}
    \newunicodechar{❾}{{\circlednum ❾}}
    \newunicodechar{❿}{{\circlednum ❿}}
    \newunicodechar{⓫}{{\circlednum ⓫}}
    \newunicodechar{⓬}{{\circlednum ⓬}}
    \newunicodechar{⓭}{{\circlednum ⓭}}
    \newunicodechar{⓮}{{\circlednum ⓮}}
    \newunicodechar{⓯}{{\circlednum ⓯}}
    \newunicodechar{⓰}{{\circlednum ⓰}}
    \newunicodechar{⓱}{{\circlednum ⓱}}
    \newunicodechar{⓲}{{\circlednum ⓲}}
    \newunicodechar{⓳}{{\circlednum ⓳}}
    \newunicodechar{⓴}{{\circlednum ⓴}}
    \makeatletter
    \def\circled#1{\expandafter\@circled\csname c@#1\endcsname}
    \def\@circled#1{%
      \ifcase#1\or ❶\or ❷\or ❸\or ❹\or ❺\or ❻\or ❼\or ❽\or ❾\or ❿\or
       ⓫\or ⓬\or ⓭\or ⓮\or ⓯\or ⓰\or ⓱\or ⓲\or ⓳\or ⓴\else\@ctrerr\fi}
    \makeatother
    \newcommand{\startcirclednumbers}{%
        \AddToHookNext{cmd/item/before}{%
          \def\labelenumi{\circled{enumi}}}}
    \let\endcirclednumbers\relax
---

A list with circled numbers:

\startcirclednumbers
<div class="circled-numbers">

1. one
2. two

</div>
\endcirclednumbers

A normal list:

1. one
2. two



Awesome! Let me try and integrate it with my pipeline…

Something is not right: your last example used literally (with fonts adjusted)—circled numbers are displayed, but not in lists. Maybe some package version issues or pandoc version?

Updated to MacTeX 2024—yupiii—it works!

@VladimirKeleshev, the hook code needs a fairly recent LaTeX format

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin = 2cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{\node[circle, draw, inner sep=0pt, minimum size = 1.3em] (char) {#1};}}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label = \protect\circled{\arabic*}]
    \item test \verb|\circled|, test \verb|\circled|
    \item test \verb|\circled|, test \verb|\circled|
    \item test \verb|\circled|, test \verb|\circled|
    \item test \verb|\circled|, test \verb|\circled|
    \item test \verb|\circled|, test \verb|\circled|
    \item test \verb|\circled|, test \verb|\circled|
    \item test \verb|\circled|, test \verb|\circled|
    \item test \verb|\circled|, test \verb|\circled|
    \item test \verb|\circled|, test \verb|\circled|
    \item test \verb|\circled|, test \verb|\circled|
    \item test \verb|\circled|, test \verb|\circled|
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}


